# How to encrypt a file on a Windows 7 machine and decrypt on Ubuntu

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, encryption

I need to encrypt a file on a Windows 7 machine, and then decrypt it on an Ubuntu machine.  What is the simplest way of doing this, preferably with tools that are likely to already be installed on the two machines.  I have cygwin on the Windows machine if needed.

Comment: I know its end of life, but I've yet to see anything that effectively replaces truecrypt. if your adversary is not a nation-state or large company engaged in industrial espionage, truecrypt 7.1a is probably still sufficient to your needs.

Comment: Zip it with a password.

Comment: @techie007 that's what I ended up doing

Answer (score 4):

OpenPGP using the GnuPG tools will likely be easiest. (GnuPG for Windows comes in both [native](http://www.gpg4win.org/) and Cygwin forms.)

To encrypt with a password:

```
gpg --symmetric myfile.txt
```

To decrypt:

```
gpg --decrypt myfile.txt.gpg
```

Comment: The `--symmetric` option by default caches your password locally and you may want to clear it with `gpg-connect-agent reloadagent /bye`

Answer (score 0):

I prefer and think that is more easy to do it using one zip archiever with pasword like winrar ow 7zip on windows, copy the file and decompress it in linux.